# Row with most recent data per user_id

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have this view but I would like to change it such that the most recent employee 'Stritt' gets all the sales cause he made the last one.

```
   cal_date     id  sales   emp
    2021-01-04  24  0.85    Krebs 
    2021-01-29  24  11.4    Krebs   
    2021-01-31  24  -5.7    Timo
    2021-02-01  24  0.85    Timo    
    2021-02-26  24  1.00    Stritt
    2021-01-30  33  5.33    Alex
    2021-03-10  33  3.45    Alex    
    2021-04-20  33  1.20    Dom
```

It should look like this:

```
   cal_date     id  sales   emp
    2021-01-04  24  0.85    Stritt
    2021-01-29  24  11.4    Stritt
    2021-01-31  24  -5.7    Stritt
    2021-02-01  24  0.85    Stritt
    2021-02-26  24  1.00    Stritt
    2021-01-30  33  5.33    Dom
    2021-03-10  33  3.45    Dom 
    2021-04-20  33  1.20    Dom
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Window function to find the last value in a partition *(the `id`)*

```
SELECT
  cal_date,
  id,
  sales,
  FIRST_VALUE(emp)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY id
          ORDER BY cal_date DESC,
                   emp      DESC
    )
      AS emp
FROM
  yourTable
```

In the case that multiple emp's have records for the latest date, the highest emp value is chosen.

Comment: @tts I'm on my phone so don't have the patience to test using dbfiddle.uk and will just trust you :)  Answer updated.

Comment: @eshirvana - Kindly do ***not*** edit other people's answers to amend ***style***.

Comment: dbfiddle using example borrowed from @dogyog : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb650a75fb68f878b1298f354f6211ce

Comment: In order to obtain result as in description have to add `ORDER BY id, cal_date` at the end :)